# Media editor backbone js: Get the current action

Tags: wordpress, backbone.js, gallery, state, shortcode

I'm creating a plugin that adds an option to the native WP gallery.

When a new gallery is created (clicking the "Create Gallery" button in the media popup), a 'select' element is added, and I have a backbone event listening for the 'change' event of this 'select'.

However, I only want to listen for the change event when the gallery is being newly created, rather than when editing an existing gallery.

My code so far is:

```
wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
                    events: function() {

                        var the_events = {};

                        //NEED TO GET STATE (ie, 'creating gallery for first time' rather than 'edit gallery'....
                        var is_create_gallery = true;

                        //IF WE'RE EDITING, SET IT TO FALSE
                        //--here--

                        if (is_create_gallery) {
                            _.extend( the_events, { 'change select[data-setting="gallerytype"]' : 'gallerytypechanged' } );
                        }

                        return the_events;
                    },
                    gallerytypechanged: function( e ){
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var self = this;

                        var gallery_type = jQuery( e.currentTarget ).val();

                        if( gallery_type != 'native' ){
                            self.update.apply( self, ['gallerytype'] );
                        }

                        return self;
                    },
                    template: function(view) {
                        return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view) + wp.media.template('gallery-type')(view);
                    },
                });
```

Basically the --here-- code should be a check to determine whether we're editing an existing gallery, or creating a new one.

Does anybody know where to check which state we're in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can detect the state of the gallery outside of your Backbone View.

You could set the `is_create_gallery` state when initializing the backbone view, then call your view constructor with the custom argument:

```
var newGallery = // determine the gallery state
var view = new wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery({newGallery: newGallery});
```

You can access the passed argument in your initialize function like this:

```
initialize: function (options) {
  if (options.newGallery) {
    _.extend(this.events, {
      'change select[data-setting="gallerytype"]' : 'gallerytypechanged'
    });
  }
}
```

Since your `events` map will be either empty or contain one event, I would remove the `events` key completely and do the events initialization from `initialize`.

Comment: Interesting idea - but as a requirement is that I 'hook in' to the native gallery, I can't create a new instance of wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.

Comment: Can you determine the state of the gallery inside the initialize function? If yes, then you can still use this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help so far. That's the issue though - I don't know how to grab the state.

Comment: Just re-reading your comment - what I actually need to do (and I guess my main question too) is determine the state of the gallery

Comment: Well, it uses Backbone (mixed with other custom functions), so no.

I suppose to be able to answer my question, one would have to know Backbone and how it's used by WordPress.